# Asymptotic variance of relative risk

Tags: variance, proportion, asymptotics, contingency-tables, relative-risk

I'm interested in the asymptotic variance of relative risk (without sample size). I know that in an application, the variance is
$$
\frac{1-p_1}{n_1p_1} + \frac{1-p_0}{n_0p_0}
$$
When removing $n$ from this formula, of course the results is values >1. I can't find any info on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wth is this? Give more context please

Comment: If something is "without sample size," then what does the variance refer to and what is changing asymptotically??  I fear that most, if not all, readers are going to find this question incomprehensible without more background and details.